# How to Create a Blog from Scratch Using Ruby on Rails - from rails 2.x to 3.x - no visable comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

Im working with How to Create a Blog from Scratch Using Ruby on Rails tutorial from sixrevisions.com.

When I run server and create new post I have no visable option to add comment. According to tutorial I should be able to add end edit comments to created posts.

My comments_controller.rb:

```
  class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
    def index
      @comments = Comment.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @comments }
      end
    end

    # GET /comments/1
    # GET /comments/1.json
     def show
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

       respond_to do |format|
         format.html # show.html.erb
         format.json { render json: @comment }
       end
    end

     # GET /comments/new
     # GET /comments/new.json
    def new
       @comment = Comment.new

       respond_to do |format|
       format.html # new.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @comment }
      end
    end

    # GET /comments/1/edit
    def edit
       @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /comments
    # POST /comments.json
    def create

        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
        redirect_to @post
    end


    # PUT /comments/1
    # PUT /comments/1.json
     def update
       @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

       respond_to do |format|
         if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
         format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully      
         updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
         else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
         format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
       end
     end

     # DELETE /comments/1
     # DELETE /comments/1.json
    def destroy
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      @comment.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end
```

Show.html.erb

```
 <p>
   <b>Title:</b>
   <%=h @post.title %>

 </p>

 <p>
   <b>Body:</b>
   <%=h @post.body %>
 </p>

 <h2>Comments</h2>

 <% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
   <p>
     <b><%=h c.name %> said:</b><br />
     <%= time_ago_in_words(c.created_at) %> ago
   </p>

   <p>
     <%=h c.body %>
   </p>
 <% end %>

 <% form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
   <p>

     <%= f.label :name, "Author" %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
     <%= f.label :body, "Comment Description" %><br />
     <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
     <%= f.submit "Add Comment" %>
  </p>
 <% end %>
```

Rake routes

```
   post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#index
                 POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new
edit_post_comment GET   /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
 post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)    comments#show
              PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
              DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
        posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
              POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
     new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
    edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
         post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
              PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
              DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                     /:controller/:action/:id(.:format)          :controller#:action
                     /:controller/:action/:id.:format            :controller#:action
         root        /                                           posts#index
```

Thanks for help & intrest!

Comment: Run `rake routes` in your terminal and tell us what the output is, please

Comment: I have added rake routes resoult to main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new link with

```
<%= link_to('new comment',new_post_path) %>
```

in your view template

Comment: Hi, I am having the exact same issue! I am just not sure where to place the link you mention on your answer @MichaelDurrant

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine.

Go to `http://localhost:3000/posts/new` and create a post. This post will have a certain id, presumably 1, if it is your first post.

Then, go to `http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments` - there you will see all comments (presumably none), and also a link to create a new comment. If there is no link, go to - you guessed it - `http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments/new`. This is just what your routes tell you.

Looks like you're using scaffolding here. I don't know the tutorial, but look into

- [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
- [Scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding)

Comment: Thans!. Those links were very usefull!